# Rails 3.1 Template Inheritance not working for js file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Rails 3.1 has Template Inheritance feature built in, very nice. But when I tried to use it with unobtrusive javascript, it doesn't work.

I have a bunch of controllers all respond to :js and all of the xxx.js.erb are almost the same, so I moved them into app/views/application folder, and then the controller just couldn't find the xxx.js.erb from that folder like it does for finding xxx.html.erb. Am I miss something or it isn't supported?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me your javascript files should be in the assets folder instead.

Comment: humm... but should I also follow the folder structure under views? like assets/javascripts/application/index.js.erb?

Comment: Yes... I believe it's considered good convention (keep frontend similar to backend)